# how to login redis 6.0+ use username and password

Tags: redis

I found the redis 6.0+ add the acl, now I want to login use the default user like this:

```
I have no name!@cruise-redis-master-0:/$ redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -a doGT233U7 -u default
Invalid URI scheme
```

I read the docs but did not find any command login into redis by username and password, what should I do to login the new version of redis above 6.0+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options:

#### Full URL

Provide the username and password in a connection string URL with the `-u` flag:

```bash
./redis-cli -u redis://<username>:<password>@<host>[:port]
```

This isn't very secure though (e.g. leaves the password in command history) so you'll get the following warning:

> Warning: Using a password with '-a' or '-u' option on the command line interface may not be safe.

#### AUTH command

The more secure method is to log in without any authentication and then execute the `AUTH` command within the CLI.

```bash
./redis-cli -h <host> [-p <port>]
AUTH [username] <password>
```